# Invoke-Expression how check if successful on Exchange CmdLet?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have to execute this Exchange command:

```
$command="Disable-Remotemailbox -Identitiy x.y@corp.com -Confirm:$false -Archive"
```

...and need to check if it was successfully executed.

```
try {
    $result = Invoke-Expression $command
    $success = 1
catch {
    $success = 0
}
```

sf

```
$result = Invoke-Expression $command
if ($?) {
   $success = 1
} else {
   $success = 0
}
```

However, this is not working like expected. It returns 1 anyways.
It seems that it only shows if the Invoke-Expression command was successful. Which is all the time.

How to archive this?

Comment: Maybe the automatic variable of `$?`

Comment: The solution is to not use `Invoke-Expression` :)

Comment: Ok i understand but whats to use? :) Start-Process? Any better way?

Comment: ok i now use a hashtable with the arguments and the call operator &